# PHP - Array no toma primer valor al seleccionar otra linea de texto

Tags: php, array

estoy teniendo un incoveniente a la hora de obtener unos datos.
Son 3 lineas diferentes separadas por comas (,).
La primera linea me la lee perfecta, ahora, cuando va a leer la segunda y tercera linea el primer valor no me lo toma como parte del array, me lo pone aparte.
Los valores son asi:

```
1,20062018,084821,100.00,01901587620817,inax123-300,PagoFacilPRUEBA,7ad3bf0c1da5cba11e2f98013d505eab8823b2daaeca363ebbfd3286c9e5eb45,c29f4c899fa23962729e69f39272ee2e7bdfa8360b013c2f9ab2f37fd8abfbd3,1
1,20062018,084721,59.99,919000043500160940000007665537000000000057,Marcelo-400,VisaPRUEBA,97f41e27be3d82c08c96ae1b2f66230b37bafbb4b54a958bc1b3f025f4a56112,47ffd120ae5c82746b59194bf8c6dc721b7df9abdda8e31c12e0756f8e0dbc47,2
1,20062018,084521,3500.00,01906409155415,Nicolas-1500,RapiPagoPRUEBA,3b07af83e76a19f6c7020ca8d08ac940ef71e7e34851596a10110a802ac7033d,37a96629e715d7fc7e2d83e2af1c8b41310b6524a9262c4940b3edf6c41bfe8b,3
3,20062018,084921,3659.99,0.00,3,d5a003c5c3337638a2f4baca970dd1f89614b4663ec4ee0d56d33e4e4f96c01b
```

El ultimo valor de la linea identifica el numero de la linea, pero el array no me lo toma y me muestra los datos así:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 20062018
    [2] => 084821
    [3] => 100.00
    [4] => 01902226247728
    [5] => asdasdsa-300
    [6] => PagoFacilPRUEBA
    [7] => ea5d299b037d2455fb3bc0af0d544a0810c53240e395b001235415479469475e
    [8] => 056577d6c33d167b991fa4963fec77aec0d7c5a24a9ed69317cd463615c976e8
    [9] => 1
1
    [10] => 20062018
    [11] => 084621
    [12] => 59.99
    [13] => 919000043500160940000004282022900000000028
    [14] => Marcelo-400
    [15] => VisaPRUEBA
    [16] => 729dd1a5a6e92f296018b5168c83ff6292cf53f8ebe6002cba9ddf00ee950278
    [17] => b21f41174e681f4ddb5393789cf9dd74b98f9ae52b79890b009e69eab11759a9
    [18] => 2
1
    [19] => 20062018
    [20] => 084721
    [21] => 3500.00
    [22] => 01909419702422
    [23] => Nicolas-1500
    [24] => RapiPagoPRUEBA
    [25] => 9d8d0073837401eb26a04f954edcc22b776ea81dc9c802a300d5390a8e185ca1
    [26] => 19002789901770eac68779a4aeaae383c40840f8974754c0fc44ea46f580708c
    [27] => 3
3
    [28] => 20062018
    [29] => 084921
    [30] => 3659.99
    [31] => 0.00
    [32] => 3
    [33] => d5a003c5c3337638a2f4baca970dd1f89614b4663ec4ee0d56d33e4e4f96c01b
)
```

Como verán son 10 valores por cada linea. pero no me lee el primero despues de leer la primera linea.

El código es el siguiente:

```
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $VALORES);
$array = array();

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $array = str_getcsv($line);


}
```

Comment: Da la impresión de que asume que la primera línea son los encabezados y por eso la ignora. [El Manual no dice nada al respecto](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-getcsv.php). Creo que vas a tener que recurrir a `fgetcsv()` u otra función más manejable.

Comment: Utilizando ese metodo solamente me lee los valores de la ultima linea

Comment: Ahi probe y utilizando el PHP_EOL me ocurre el error que comente en la publicación, si pongo "," solo me toma un valor

Comment: Prueba como ha dicho @Carmen en su respuesta.

Comment: Está solucionado, por si te interesa leer los comentarios mas abajo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El resultado que tiene parece indicar que el problema es que el `array` lines sólo tiene un elemento, es decir, la separación que tienes entre las líneas no está siendo reconocida utilizando `PHP_EOL`, por eso te pone todo en un array en el cada elemento es la separación por ",", que es el delimitador por defecto de la función [str_getcsv()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-getcsv.php).

Si fuera reconocida el resultado esperado sería un array con número de elementos igual al número de líneas y cada uno formado por un array de 10 elementos. Puedes verlo si ejecutas este ejemplo:

```
$text = "1,20062018,084821,100.00,01901587620817,inax123-300,PagoFacilPRUEBA,7ad3bf0c1da5cba11e2f98013d505eab8823b2daaeca363ebbfd3286c9e5eb45,c29f4c899fa23962729e69f39272ee2e7bdfa8360b013c2f9ab2f37fd8abfbd3,1
1,20062018,084721,59.99,919000043500160940000007665537000000000057,Marcelo-400,VisaPRUEBA,97f41e27be3d82c08c96ae1b2f66230b37bafbb4b54a958bc1b3f025f4a56112,47ffd120ae5c82746b59194bf8c6dc721b7df9abdda8e31c12e0756f8e0dbc47,2
1,20062018,084521,3500.00,01906409155415,Nicolas-1500,RapiPagoPRUEBA,3b07af83e76a19f6c7020ca8d08ac940ef71e7e34851596a10110a802ac7033d,37a96629e715d7fc7e2d83e2af1c8b41310b6524a9262c4940b3edf6c41bfe8b,3";
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $text);
var_dump($lines);
$array = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $array[] = str_getcsv($line);   

}
var_dump($array);
```

Revisa el tipo de separación entre las líneas para que el `explode` inicial funcione correctamente.

Comment: Vos sabes que me paso algo interesante... SI coloco ese Script en un Hosting cPanel funciona bien, ahora, yo estoy trabajando en XAMPP, coloco el mismo script y tengo el problema que menciono en el tema, sera la version de php?

Comment: Pues es posible, la verdad es que no se me había ocurrido asociarlo con la versión de php, interesante. ¿Has probado a hacer el explode de líneas con \n y/o \r como separadores por si es cuestión del PHP_EOL?

Comment: Instale la nueva version de XAMPP y sigue pasando lo mismo, pero en hosting anda bien, es rarisimo, con \n probe y me devuelve una sola linea

Comment: Por eso no va con PHP_EOL, ¿y \r?

Comment: LISTO!! al cambiar la version PHP probe  con \n y funciono! \r me devuelve lo mismo que PHP_EOL!! Muchas Gracias por la ayuda y predisposición!

Comment: Un placer, y una cosa más que sabemos. Deja anotada la versión de PHP con la que no funciona por si a alguien más le sucede en el futuro.

Comment: PHP Version 7.2.6

Comment: @IgnacioCopparoni no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si resolvió tu problema. Por otra parte, no me he enterado bien de eso de `PHP_EOL` ¿?  Según tengo entendido es la forma más segura de saltos de línea, porque es multiplataforma.

Comment: Parece ser que hay esa versión de PHP en Xamp le estaba dando un fallo y PHP_EOL no reconocía la separación de línea, a pesar de ser el modo más seguro de hacerlo. Puede ser un  problema PHP-Xamp resuelto en una versión posterior o algo puntual por configuración.